# Matplotlib gives unexpected shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geometry-surface

I am trying to surface plot a geometrical function:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import pylab
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
theta, phi = np.linspace(1e-5, 2 * np.pi-0.001, 400), np.linspace(1e-5, 3*np.pi/5.5, 400)
PHI, THETA = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
theta1 = np.sqrt(7.5*(-1+np.sqrt(1-0.8*0.1*1./8.*(-8. + THETA*(5 + 3.*np.cos(2*PHI))/np.tan(THETA) + (5. + np.cos(THETA))* (np.sin(PHI))**2))))
R = (np.sin(theta1)+0.00000001)/(np.sin(theta1 + THETA)+0.00000001)
X = R * np.cos(THETA)
Y = R * np.sin(THETA) * np.cos(PHI)
Z = R * np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

At the nose, I get a kink which is not expected at all. I should get a smooth paraboloid type towards the nose. Is there any way to smoothen this out?

Note: If I try `SphericalPlot3D` in `Mathematica`, I do not get any such problem. 
[image: plot the above code produces]

Comment: Drawing a contour plot of the same data gives the same kind of kink close to the tip. Are you sure that your `theta1` calculation is correct?

Comment: I am certain that `theta1` calculation is correct. In fact drawing the same in `Mathematica` gives no such kink.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was just wondering whether there could be a small typo somewhere. Happens to me all the time...

Comment: Yeah, I did a double check, and `theta1` is definitely correct. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, but then it doesn't seem to be a problem with the 3d surface rendering, because, as I said, the same kink appears with a contour plot. This almost sounds like a numerical discrepancy.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that it was numerical discrepancy. Writing `theta1` as a series of `Sin[PHI]^0` and `Sin[PHI]^2` removed this kink.